# convert 3d array to 2d array in php

Tags: php

I have an array in the format:

```
 array (
      [0] => array (
        [0] => array (
          [id] =>  19
          [Type] =>  sng
          [TouristPrice] =>  2500
          [ExtraBeds] =>  1500
          [ChildPrice] => 1000
        )
      )
    )
```

And I'd like to convert it to:

```
array (
    [0] => array (
      [id] =>  19
      [Type] =>  sng
      [TouristPrice] =>  2500
      [ExtraBeds] =>  1500
      [ChildPrice] => 1000
    )  
)
```

How might I go about doing this?

Comment: loop to iterate and create a new array with the new structure.

Comment: Voting to close as too localized.

Comment: $newarray = $oldarray[0];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you can do is, walking through the array and putting the first option this way, in case, all the array items will be of the same kind, having only one level deep. It is just like moving a folder inside a folder, to the parent folder:

```
foreach ($array as $subarray)
    $subarray = $subarray[0];
```

---

Tried this code:

```
<?php
    $array = array(
        array(
            array(
                "Hello",
                "World"
            )
        ),
        array(
            array(
                "Hello One",
                "World One"
            )
        ),
    );
    var_dump($array);
    foreach ($array as $subarray)
        $subarray = $subarray[0];
    var_dump($array);
?>
```

Got this output:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(5) "Hello"
      [1]=>
      string(5) "World"
    }
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(9) "Hello One"
      [1]=>
      string(9) "World One"
    }
  }
}
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(5) "Hello"
      [1]=>
      string(5) "World"
    }
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(9) "Hello One"
      [1]=>
      string(9) "World One"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Don't you need to use `&$subarray` to use a reference rather than a copy, or am I talking nonsense?

Comment: @TomWalters Er... Am not sure. Will try it out and update the answer. :)

Comment: Yep I think it should be: `foreach ($array as &$subarray)`

Comment: Actually, no difference. You are storing the array as a variable. Not the address. :)