# How can I remove array braces in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array -given below, which consists array indice(s). I want to remove the outer most array bracket - which add an additional square bracket in my JSON data. I tried to reduce one bracket by doing $aaray[0], $array[1]....but I am not satisfied with this solution,as I have to run an additional for loop which disturbs my outer foreach loop.

```
  $value['ranges'] =
      array(            
          array(
             'monthindex' => $numOfmonths,           
             'laps'  => $value['recurring_by'],
             'start' => "a1",
             'end'   => "a2",           
              ),
         array(
            'monthindex' => $numOfmonths,
            'laps'  => $value['recurring_by'],
            'start' => "b1",
            'end'   => "b2",            
            )
        );

   // $numOfmonths--;

$monthItems[] = $value;
```

for more clarification if you want to see the print_r() format.

```
[ranges] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [monthindex] => 3
                                [laps] => 2
                                [start] => a1
                                [end] => a2

                            )

                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [monthindex] => 3
                                [laps] => 2
                                [start] => b1
                                [end] => b2

                            )

                    )

            )
```

Is there any way I can remove the the outermost **Array()**  before assigning $value to $monthItems[]  ? Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Add your code or  o/p you want

Comment: Without outermost array how will you store two array ?

Comment: @Priyank , do need additional code or what does 0/p refer to ?

Comment: @AkshayHegde, actually this code is being executed in a foreachloop, on runtime can we reduce one [ ] and assign $monthItems[] = $value;

Comment: @Verdu tell me exactly o/p you want for above question

Comment: @Verdu: please show expected output as well

Comment: @Verdu remove [] bracket from monthItems
$monthItems = $value;
or directly print $value

Comment: @Priyank , its a dynamic array I have to assign multiple values so the values are not static and the array has to be dynamic.

Comment: @Verdu check this ans.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14621060/convert-3d-array-to-2d-array-in-php

Comment: @Priyank this is the Js Obj [[{"id":"5","color":"red",nges":[{"monthindex":3},{"monthindex":3"}]},{"id":"5","color":"red""nges":[{"monthindex":3"},{"monthindex":3"}]}]] , I need to trim the outermost square bracket

Answer (score 2):

`$value['ranges']` can only have one value.

Currently the value is an array. That array contains two values.

If you removed that array, then you could only assign one of those two values to `$value['ranges']`.

So you cannot remove the outer array without also removing one of the two values it holds.

Comment: Yes , this is what actually happening.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 

$ary['ranges'][] = ['monthindex'=>3, 'laps'=>2, 'start'=>'a1', 'end'=>'a2']; 
$ary['ranges'][] = ['monthindex'=>3, 'laps'=>2, 'start'=>'b1', 'end'=>'b2', 'test'=>['a'=>['b'=>1]]]; 



function deep_scan_array( $ary, $count=0 ) {
    if(is_array($ary)) {
        foreach($ary as $key=>$item){
            if(is_array($item)){
                echo str_repeat("\t", $count);
                echo "[$key] => array\n";
                deep_scan_array($item, $count+1);
            }else{
                echo str_repeat("\t", $count);
                echo "[$key]=>$item\n";
            }
        }
    }
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($ary);
deep_scan_array($ary);
```

Output:

```
[ranges] => array
    [0] => array
        [monthindex]=>3
        [laps]=>2
        [start]=>a1
        [end]=>a2
    [1] => array
        [monthindex]=>3
        [laps]=>2
        [start]=>b1
        [end]=>b2
        [test] => array
            [a] => array
                [b]=>1
```